# SQL IN Clause replacement Temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My query is :

```
Select * 
from Person 
where KV_CODE IN('','',''......1000 values here)
```

How to write this list of values in a temp table so that I can replace IN clause with a join to increase performance.

This list of values is coming on the basis of random selection by user and is stored in a Java collection.

Comment: You can use `SELECT` as inner query to retrieve those values.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Performance issues are often product specific, since different products have different optimize techniques.

Comment: DBMS SQL SERVER, also tagged

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Person
where KV_CODE in (
    select KV_CODE
    from TempTable
)
```

This will compare the KV_CODE of Person to the KV_CODE of TempTable. If there are matches, it will intersect them, meaning your first select will print only those rows.

```
select *
from Person p
join TempTable tmp
on p.KV_CODE = tmp.KV_CODE
```

This will join the two tables and display the matching rows from both tables.

Unless your question is "how to populate a temporary table from a java collection"

Comment: Yes, you are right Fredrik, my question is how to populate a temporary table from a java collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Person P INNER JOIN #Temp T ON T.KV_CODE = P.KV_CODE
```

You can apply `INNER JOIN` on Temp Table similar to Normal Tables.

Answer (score 0):

Newer database solutions optimize this already. There is not much difference between IN clause and Join as optimizer figures out this aspect and execute query by appropriate path.

If you still wish, here is what you have to do.
if you are using Oracle,

1. you can create a session scope or transaction scope temporary table.
2. Insert data into this temporary table
3. Fire query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM PERSONS T1, 
     TEMP_TABLE_NAME_HERE T2 
WHERE T1.KV_CODE = T2.KV_CODE
```

However, a better solution is to avoid temp table creation during run time. You can actually create a permanent table in your application database with some unique key to identify your session (to isolate cross session impacts, i.e 2 users using same functionality).

```
CREATE TABLE KV_TEMP_TABLE 
(SESSION_ID VARCHAR2(100), 
KV_CODE VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

--Adjust datatypes suitably

Then your query should look like

```
SELECT * FROM PERSONS T1, KV_TEMP_TABLE T2 
WHERE T2.SESSION_ID = ? 
AND T1.KV_CODE = T2.KV_CODE
```

--Bind your session id 
Before issuing this query, you have to populate data into `KV_TEMP_TABLE`  using normal insert statements (along with a session id).

Comment: Actually my project uses older version of SQL SERVER, for long list in IN clause causes Query processor ran out of memory exception. To avoid that I have to replace IN with join

Comment: @ManishKapasiya, Oh! That makes sense. Then I would suggest to go with method 2 suggested above. In case of too many values, consider adding index to boost performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example to populates a temp table :

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
EmployeeID INT,
Certs VARCHAR(8000)
)
INSERT @t VALUES (1,'B.E.,MCA, MCDBA, PGDCA'), (2,'M.Com.,B.Sc.'), (3,'M.Sc.,M.Tech.')

SELECT EmployeeID,
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Certs
FROM
(
SELECT EmployeeID,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(Certs,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM   @t
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
```

Once the temp table @t is populated, it can be used with JOINs to get the desired output.